# Creating a Data URI's from SCSS

Tags: svg, sass, compass-sass, data-uri

I am trying to get a SVG to process into a DATA URI, It would make my code a lot easier to maintain, rather than reams of code.

```
$white:rgb(255,255,255);

background:$white inline_image("/images/select-arrows.svg") no-repeat 92% center;
```

This is what I have to far, I am using modernizr for fallback however I am manually using an online converter, I am running scss with compass installed. These are being complied by codekit 2.

Compass Config:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "fonts"

output_style = :compressed
color_output = false
```

Below is my current markup:

```
background:$white url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjwhLS0gR2VuZXJhdG9yOiBBZG9iZSBJbGx1c3RyYXRvciAxNy4xLjAsIFNWRyBFeHBvcnQgUGx1Zy1JbiAuIFNWRyBWZXJzaW9uOiA2LjAwIEJ1aWxkIDApICAtLT4NCjwhRE9DVFlQRSBzdmcgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBTVkcgMS4xLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL0dyYXBoaWNzL1NWRy8xLjEvRFREL3N2ZzExLmR0ZCI+DQo8c3ZnIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgaWQ9IkxheWVyXzEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4Ig0KCSB3aWR0aD0iMTBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNnB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAgMTYiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDEwIDE2IiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj4NCjxwb2x5Z29uIGZpbGw9IiM0NzRDNEMiIHBvaW50cz0iMTAsOS43NDYgNS4wNTgsMTYgMCw5Ljc0NiAiLz4NCjxwb2x5Z29uIGZpbGw9IiM0NzRDNEMiIHBvaW50cz0iMCw2LjI5MSA1LDAgMTAsNi4yOTEgIi8+DQo8Zz4NCjwvZz4NCjxnPg0KPC9nPg0KPGc+DQo8L2c+DQo8Zz4NCjwvZz4NCjxnPg0KPC9nPg0KPGc+DQo8L2c+DQo8Zz4NCjwvZz4NCjxnPg0KPC9nPg0KPGc+DQo8L2c+DQo8Zz4NCjwvZz4NCjxnPg0KPC9nPg0KPGc+DQo8L2c+DQo8Zz4NCjwvZz4NCjxnPg0KPC9nPg0KPGc+DQo8L2c+DQo8L3N2Zz4NCg==) no-repeat 92% center;
```

Any feedback would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Almost there](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/#inline-image):

```
background:$white inline-image("select-arrows.svg") no-repeat 92% center;
```

Make sure your `images_dir` is set correctly in your `config.rb` to point to `./images` (which is the default) and you should be good to go.

Also, [check out this post](http://matt.scharley.me/2013/11/compass-inline-svg-png-fallback-with-sprites.html) to see some neat tricks with Compass and inline'd SVG's with fallback PNG's (yes, you should be using fallbacks still). SVG's isn't anywhere near supported universally yet.

Comment: nice, I guess I did not take the dir into consideration, and yes that mixin looks sweet!