# SCSS variable in background image with SVG image data URI

Tags: css, svg, sass, data-uri

In the following SCSS, I would like to use the `fg-color` variable within the `url` `background-image` attribute.

```
$fg-color: #ff6464;

i.icon-back {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M10,0l2,2l-8,8l8,8l-2,2L0,10L10,0z' fill='%23ff6464'/></svg>");
}
```

At the moment the value, of the variable in simply repeated within the SVG string, like so:

```
fill='%23ff6464'
```

I would like this to be automatically updated whenever the `fg-color` variable is updated.

How can I do this?

---

UPDATE:

This input SCSS:

```
i.icon-back {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M10,0l2,2l-8,8l8,8l-2,2L0,10L10,0z' fill='$fg-color'/></svg>");
}
```

Outputs this CSS:

```
i.icon-back {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M10,0l2,2l-8,8l8,8l-2,2L0,10L10,0z' fill='$fg-color'/></svg>");
}
```

... it is exactly the same - the variable is not processed.

---

NOTE:

I have reviewed these questions, that appear to be similar, but are not the same:

- [Creating a Data URI's from SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22323021/194982)
- [Using an Data URI SVG as a CSS background image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13742934/194982)

Comment: @cimmanon I'll ignore the snarkiness of your comment. Anyway, yes, I have tried using the variable, and the output that I get doesn't do any substitution at all. I'll update my question to show exactly what I get.

Comment: @cimmanon I have found a way to do this. It turns out that it was a more complicated than simply "using the variable".

Answer (score 43):

First, create a SASS function.
This (ab)uses string interpolation to convert the colour to a string, 
and then strips the first character (should always be '`#`'),
and puts '`%23`' in its place (URL encoded form of '`#`').

```
@function url-friendly-colour($colour) {
    @return '%23' + str-slice('#{$colour}', 2, -1)
}
```

Then use the function - but in order for it to work within the string, it *must* be interpolated, using `#{}`

```
i.icon-back {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M10,0l2,2l-8,8l8,8l-2,2L0,10L10,0z' fill='#{url-friendly-colour($fg-color)}'/></svg>");
}
```

The caveat with this approach, of course, is that it will not work with colours
that are specified by colour name instead of their hexadecimal colour.

E.g. `#f00` works but `red` will not.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, which browser were you using? For me just using `fill="#{$color}"` works just fine.

Comment: @JureTriglav all of them (including IE)

Comment: Yes, should work with anything above IE 8. Is the `url-friendly-colour` required for cross-browser support? From my testing it isn't necessary, and simply interpolating a color directly works: `fill="#{$color}`.

Comment: Thanx! Worked for me. In Chrome I had it working by using:

`fill='#{$fg-color'}`

But Firefox wouldn't accept this. I could use rgb() color definitions, that works too. But I your SASS function better...

Comment: This is years later but I just used @JureTriglav option and it worked easiest.

Comment: I found this site useful for giving you the perfectly encoded URL ready for use: yoksel.github.io/url-encoder - Just copy the SVG code into it and copy out the returned CSS :-)

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer to your question, but an alternative way to achieve a similar result in many cases (think simple mono-color icons). You can use CSS mask-image like so:

```
i.icon-back {
  background-color: $fg-color; 
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg…');
}
```

[Browser support for CSS masks](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) is missing Edge/IE at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution

```
// SASS 
$nt-link-color
.circle{
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style='fill:#{toRGB($nt-link-color)};' width='24' height='28' viewBox='0 0 24 28'><path d='M24 14c0 6.625-5.375 12-12 12s-12-5.375-12-12 5.375-12 12-12 12 5.375 12 12z'></path></svg>")  no-repeat;
}

// FUNCTION
@function toRGB ($color) {
  @return "rgb(" + red($color) + ", " + green($color) + ", " + blue($color)+ ")";
}
```

Comment: svg doesn't show up

Comment: @KVM that's because the `#` hasn't been encoded. use `%23` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [postcss-inline-svg](https://github.com/TrySound/postcss-inline-svg) plugin like this :

in `_variable.scss`

```scss
    $text-primary-100 : #11091a;
    ...
```

in `_header.scss` :

```scss
    .logo {
        width: 154px;
        height:32px;
        background: svg-load("../assets/logo/logo.svg", fill=$text-primary-100) center no-repeat;
    }
```

this will become :

```scss
.nav {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg fill='%11091a'%3E%3Cpath d='...'/%3E%3Cpath d='...' fill='%11091a'/%3E%3Cpath d='...'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```