# CSS SVG background image Hex color variable not working

Tags: html, css, svg

Please take a look at the code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/hkcLy02m/)

I need to use color variables `(Eg: $primary)` in SVG background image code, because of multiple color themes in my website. When we add `$primary` value as a direct color (Eg: `$primary: blue`) it will work. But HEX color codes (`$primary: #1828B4`) are not rendering in output.

I know using `%` instead of `#` will solve the problem. But this case it is not possible while we are using color variables!

Please advise any solution.

Comment: The demo on the linked JSFiddle seems to work fine. Changing `$primary: red` to `$primary: #0000ff` works without issues.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro global color codes may work. But custom not.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro that's because SCSS silently converts `#0000ff` to `blue`, so it will work only for named colours.

Comment: See / kinda duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477819/scss-variable-in-background-image-with-svg-image-data-uri

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to use the following:

SCSS file:

```
$primary: #CCC;

.svg {
  stroke: $primary;
}
```

Comment: OP is using SVG as DataURI background image, so the output string must be in URI encoded. Sadly SCSS does not know that and prints (non-named) colour verbatim, including `#` what finishes the DataURI payload. (It has to be encoded as `%23`.)

Comment: I remember I used to use a function in SASS that converts them to encoded URIs (yes, its possible to make SASS do it!).

Comment: Some SASS function doing that is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478589/540955